# Using Bing Custom Search to integrate results from Bing for Business

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-functions

Team,

I have gone through the articles for Microsoft search for bing.com. It says we have to enable few features in Azure. Once we have configured in Azure portal through orgnaization login we can retrieve resulst from both organization results and web results in bing.com.

Now, I want to bring the same functionality in Sharepoint online(SPO) through custom code. So how to integerate both organizantion search and web results in one page list Microsoft search in bing.

Thanks a ton !!

-Dhana

Answer (score 0):

You can enable this functionality in the O365 admin center, no code required.

https://practical365.com/microsoft-365/how-to-enable-search-in-office-365/